# RxJava's takeLast method does not act as JavaDoc described

Tags: rx-java

I tried below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Observable.interval(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .take(7)
      .takeLast(2, 2100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .subscribe(System.out::println);
  Thread.sleep(5000L);
}
```

I expected that I would get `2`, `3`.

```
time: 0...500...1000...1500...2000...2500...3000
emit: 0...1.....2......3......4......5......6
takeLast:.......X......X.....................
param's time...[...........2100ms..............]
```

but the result was `5`, `6`.

To me, it is not that the JavaDoc described in the marble diagram.

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeLast%28int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29

Is this(`5`, `6`) right?
If so, what the difference between this method and `takeLast(int count)`?
Does the time parameter mean anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I guess your assumption would be `3` and `4` instead of `2` and `3`, given that there is also a value at `t=2000ms`?

You need to read very carefully here (got it wrong the first time I used this myself as well): "*Returns: an `Observable` that emits at most `count` items from the source `Observable` that were **emitted in a specified window of time before the `Observable` completed***"

So, your `Observable` completes after emitting 7 elements, due to `take(7)`. Then you ask for (substituting in the italic sentence) "*an `Observable` that emits at most **2 items** from the source `Observable` that were emitted in **in the LAST 2100ms** before the `Observable` completed*". What you are assuming is the values in the **FIRST** 2100ms, which is not the case with this overload of the `takeLast` operator.

If you instead want something that does what your ASCII-diagram draws, I guess you need to use [`take(2100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#take(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and [`take(2)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#take(int)) instead of `take(7).last(2, 2100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`.

Finally, your question on whether there is a difference between `take(7)` and `take(2, 2100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`: yes, the former is guaranteed to give you the last 7 items (assuming there were 7 or more items in the stream of course), whereas the latter gives you **at most** 2 items, only if there were any in the last 2100ms before the `onCompleted` was called.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Now I got the difference `takeLast(2)` and `takeLast(2, 2100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`. If the time were too shrot, such as `takeLast(2, 100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`, the observable would emit less than 2 items.  
  
  But I am still confusing the JavaDoc's marble diaglam.  [javadoc link](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeLast%28int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)  
  If the takeLast method gain the last 1 items, in the JavaDoc's marble diaglam, the observable must emit the purple item instead of the blue item.

Comment: The marble diaglam looks like that `takeLast(1, 2100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` is the same as `takeLast(2100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).take(1)`.

Comment: Now I see what you mean regarding the JavaDoc's marble diagram. You're either correct in your second comment or you discovered a bug... Indeed the marble diagram in fact shows: "*an `Observable` that emits at most **the first** `count` items from the source `Observable` that were emitted in a specified window of time before the `Observable` completed*". Maybe you can look into this a bit and see whether this is the behavior in the API. If not, I guess you can create an issue at the RxJava repository.

Comment: I created the [issue#3957](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3957). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the marble diagram again. It seems to be working exactly as described i.e.

```
time: 0...500...1000...1500...2000...2500...3000
emit: 0...1.....2......3......4......5......6
takeLast:............................X......X
param's time......................[..2100ms.]
```

Comment: At first, I thought so. But, if so, when I put `takeLast(2, 1400L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`, I would get 3 and 4. If takeLast method got the last 2 item in the time woindow, I wondered what is the difference from takeLast(2), since takeLast method would get the last items anyway.

Comment: Think of the window as starting from the end (right) not the start (left). That means `takeLast(2, 1400L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` takes at most two emitted items in the last 1400 milliseconds before the source observable completes.